# Update array elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, overwrite

I feel like I'm overlooking something extremely simple here, but I can't see why this is failing.

My function (at bottom of the page) works well, if I call the newProp() function and comment out the `IF STATEMENT` that determines whether newProp() or existingProp() is called. If I keep the `IF STATEMENT` in, then existingProp() will successfully acknowledge (via alert box) if I've left any of the mandatory fields blank. If I fill out all the mandatory fields though, existingProp() doesn't seem to do anything. It doesn't look like it's updating my array using the `properties[currentArrayID][x]` code, which should overwrite properties[currentArrayID] with the new set of info stored in variables.

```
properties[currentArrayID][0] = currentPID;
properties[currentArrayID][1] = number;
properties[currentArrayID][2] = street;
properties[currentArrayID][3] = suburb;
properties[currentArrayID][4] = postcode;
properties[currentArrayID][5] = status;
properties[currentArrayID][6] = owner;
properties[currentArrayID][7] = ownernum;
properties[currentArrayID][8] = tenant;
properties[currentArrayID][9] = tenantnum;

document.frmPropData.txtNumber.value = "";
document.frmPropData.txtStreet.value = "";
document.frmPropData.txtSuburb.value = "";
document.frmPropData.txtPostcode.value = "";
document.frmPropData.drpStatus.value = "NA";
document.frmPropData.txtOwner.value = "";
document.frmPropData.txtOwnerNum.value = "";
document.frmPropData.txtTenant.value = "";
document.frmPropData.txtTenantNum.value = "";
document.frmPropData.txtPID.value = "TBD";
```

but once I try to include it in my function, the function ceases to work.
The full function is as below:

```
var properties = [];
var i = 0;
var x = 1;

var number = "";
var street = "";
var suburb = "";
var postcode = "";
var status = "";
var owner = "";
var ownernum = "";
var tenant = "";
var tenantnum = "";
var propID = "";

var tenantDetails = "";

var currentPID = "";
var currentArrayID = "";

function newProperty() {
    number = document.frmPropData.txtNumber.value;
    street = document.frmPropData.txtStreet.value;
    suburb = document.frmPropData.txtSuburb.value;
    postcode = document.frmPropData.txtPostcode.value;
    status = document.frmPropData.drpStatus.value;
    owner = document.frmPropData.txtOwner.value;
    ownernum = document.frmPropData.txtOwnerNum.value;
    tenant = document.frmPropData.txtTenant.value;
    tenantnum = document.frmPropData.txtTenantNum.value;
    propID = x;


    if (tenant != "") {
        tenantDetails = tenant + " - " + tenantnum
    } else {
        tenantDetails = "Not Applicable"
    }

    //store value of current PropertyID
    currentPID = document.frmPropData.txtPID.value;
    currentArrayID = currentPID - 1;

    //check if PropertyID already exists
    if (currentPID != "TBD") {
        existingProp();
    } else { 
        newProp();
    }
}

function existingProp() {
    //check for blank entries
    if (number != "" && street != "" && suburb != "" && postcode != "" && status != "NA" && owner != "" && ownernum != "") {
        properties[currentArrayID][0] = currentPID;
        properties[currentArrayID][1] = number;
        properties[currentArrayID][2] = street;
        properties[currentArrayID][3] = suburb;
        properties[currentArrayID][4] = postcode;
        properties[currentArrayID][5] = status;
        properties[currentArrayID][6] = owner;
        properties[currentArrayID][7] = ownernum;
        properties[currentArrayID][8] = tenant;
        properties[currentArrayID][9] = tenantnum;

        document.frmPropData.txtNumber.value = "";
        document.frmPropData.txtStreet.value = "";
        document.frmPropData.txtSuburb.value = "";
        document.frmPropData.txtPostcode.value = "";
        document.frmPropData.drpStatus.value = "NA";
        document.frmPropData.txtOwner.value = "";
        document.frmPropData.txtOwnerNum.value = "";
        document.frmPropData.txtTenant.value = "";
        document.frmPropData.txtTenantNum.value = "";
        document.frmPropData.txtPID.value = "TBD";
        alert("no blanks found")
    } else {
        alert("Please complete all fields marked with an asterisk *")
    }
}
```

To give more context, this function detects the value in a form field named txtPID and stores it in currentPID. The value starts at 1, so another variable called currentArrayID is equal to currentPID minus 1, to determine the array index. If the txtPID field value is "TBD", any data entered into the form is appended to the array using a push. Otherwise, the form is already populated with array elements, so the function should overwrite those elements.

**Edited to simplify code**

Comment: Where does `properties` come from?

Comment: properties is the name of my array. It's defined globally.

Comment: What does it contain? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Please show us how you're calling the function.

Comment: What do you mean by `the function ceases to work`

Comment: is `properties` an array or an object?

Comment: I'm calling the function via an onclick on a button.
properties is an array.

Comment: Morlo, if I comment out the mentioned lines, and replace them with an alert, for example, the alert shows correctly, indicating that my if statement is working. Additionally, my properties.push to add to my array works, and then the form fields are cleared.

Once I add those code lines back in, nothing happens when calling on the function. The alert doesn't show and the fields don't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I've now resolved this.

So the form has a field for a "Property ID" which has a value of "TBD". Upon clicking in the first field of the form, the Property ID field gets updated to a value of 1. Each time the form is saved, the variable increments and sets the field back to TBD. The next time the first field is selected it will update the Property ID to a value of 2, and so on.
Additionally, if I recall an existing record, all the fields, including the Property ID, will populate with the details of the record, pulled from an array. What this means is, at no point in time, when I click the button that calls on the `newProperty()` function, will the Property ID field have a value of "TBD". So I had to instead check if the array index exists.

Therefore I changed

```
//check if PropertyID already exists
    if (currentPID != "TBD") {
        existingProp();
    } else { 
        newProp();
    }
```

to

```
    //check if PropertyID already exists
    if (typeof properties[currentArrayID] ==='undefined') {
        newProp();
    } else { 
        existingProp();
    }
```

and it is now working.